# Email username for automated emails

Tags: email, names

What would you suggest to use as a cool, friendly username for automated emails? So for example if a user signs up he receives a welcome email with his login details from certain address like `info@example.com` or `system@example.com`.

Do you have any better ideas than `info` or `system`? I don't want it to be offensive nor funny but friendly and welcoming and usable for all automated emails, not just for welcome email.

Comment: Hugely related: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/11465/what-is-the-best-email-username-to-use-for-a-myname-com-domain (And you should really accept the answer you used, or found most helpful)

Comment: Ok. Zhank you for reference btw, though it's more about personal e-mails

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd suggest just having the email be 'from' somebody's name — so that the person who receives it can reply, even to automated messages, to a human.

Ideally the name of the actual human being who is primarily responsible for the emails that go out. A salesperson if it's sales. A founder / product manager for app related stuff. A marketer if it's advertising.

People relate to people.

The automated mails we send out mostly come from me. My name. My email. That's produced a *stupid* amount of useful feedback over time, and more and better feedback than when we had generic "From" emails like info@, team@, crew@, etc.

For example I suspect that few subscribers think that I send our Agile & Lean UX newsletter by hand. The Mailchimp footer is probably a bit of a give away ;) But the email is "from" me and I read the replies.

(Aside: I never understand folk who setup automated mails so that replies end up being thrown away. At least until you reach the point where the number of replies become unmanageable. This is your customer trying to talk to you. This is gold! Why the heck would you ignore that! Yes, it might not scale when you get to thousands of users. But wait until you get to that point first!)

Comment: I am on the fence about this. While I can see why you would simulate a person when sending these emails. I find that it's painfully obvious that they are automated and the user is being made 'fun' of. I find that humans and machines should be separated, automatic replies should be clearly labelled as such.

Comment: You're not a fan of Mrs 'do-not-reply@' then? She seems to work at a lot of companies I get emails from.

Comment: I'm fine with Mrs Do-not-reply'. I find that when I get a mail such as 'Hi, XX, this is Ben from XXX'. When I know Ben usually does not exist.

Comment: @DanielZahra - I think you can do both. You can make it obvious that it's an automated mail, but also have a human as the sender.

For example I suspect that few subscribers think that I send our Agile & Lean UX newsletter by hand. The Mailchimp footer is probably a bit of a give away ;) But the email is "from" me and I read the replies.

I'll clarify the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Fill in the second two bullets with your relevant info.

- support@mydomain.com
- yourproductname@mydomain.com
- yourcompanyname@mydomain.com

Answer (score 2):

*noreply@domain.com* is a popular convention; it makes it clear to the user that the e-mail has been sent automatically and it doesn't really make sense to spend time on responding to it.

Comment: Surely a 'noreply' email is akin to just running up to people in the street, shouting stuff at them and then running off without giving them any opportunity to respond to you? i.e. spam.

Comment: @JonW there is a huge difference between receiving informative messages that don't require answer and receiving garbage that you don't even want to see.

Comment: Messages might not require an answer, but they might prompt questions. And a noreply email address basically tells the recipient *"If you don't understand or don't like anything in this email, or even if you do, then you can't tell us about it"*

Comment: No... It's just an e-mail address for automated messages that indicates that none  questions should not be sent to _this particular_ address. When you get a text from your bank or pizza delivery service, pretty much the same thing happens. There is a different e-mail for support and different for automated messages.

Comment: The pizza one is a great example though - if I order a pizza and get an email saying "it's on its way to number 5 evergreen terrace" but I live at number 15 that means I'm going to have a panic, have to then hunt around the website for the contact details so I can amend my order quickly. If I could just reply to the email and say "Oops, wrong address it's actually number 15" that'd save me a lot of stress.

Comment: Design is about taking costs into consideration too. Design is not always about making everything perfect to the user. Paying the cost of making this e-mail 'answerable' is also a business issue.

Comment: "Noreply" is a standard and could figure here in this question, but the OP specified: "cool, friendly username".

Comment: Being a standard makes is somewhat of friendly... Coolness could be a matter of discussion though; depends, what kind of coolness you urge for I guess...

Comment: I also do not want to use **support@mydomain.com** for sending automated security notification emails (password changes, login attempts) etc. It implies that someone is going to respond to your replies, when in fact the system sent the email. **support@** works well when someone is going to answer that question. **no-reply@** makes it very obvious that it won't be replied to.

Answer (score 2):

I support adrianh answer but I'll present a more structured alternative:

Why not using a more semantic address?
 Example:
If it's for a welcome email **why not just use welcome@mydomain.com**?

Inside your email you can **be explicit about what's the address for receiving feedback** (also you could use feedback@mydomain.com or contact@mydomain.com). The positive side of this is that is really easy to remember without the need of being positioned inside an email as clicking reply.

Answer (score 2):

I signed up to [The Noun Project](http://thenounproject.com) recently, and their approach was new to me and that might meet your stated goal.

**yourfriends@thenounproject.com**

Friendly, and it reads like you want it to sound.

Answer (score 1):

robot@mydomain.com

Usable to many purposes, cool and friendly (IMO)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use **single email** for everything. To make it more relevant to your users, you should use at least few different emails that could cater to different use cases:

1. support@domain.com - for support purposes, can be used for welcome emails
2. noreply@domain.com - for system notifications
3. billing@domain.com - for billing and finance related emails

etc

This makes it easier for the user to send emails too. If I have billing related issue, I know which email to send etc.

Comment: Don't worry, the question says only "for all AUTOMATED emails", but I agree with you anyway.