# What are the best email address with both user experience and less spams for company?

Tags: email, names

I am freelancer and I read [What is the best email username to use for a myname.com domain?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/11465/what-is-the-best-email-username-to-use-for-a-myname-com-domain) just now.

I have build emails for many clients after building their websites.

I generally create (I suggested them most time to create emails like this) info@example.com, support@example.com, sales@example.com

But there was a comment on above linked article. It is,

> Just don't use info, webmaster, sales, support, administrator, etc.
>   etc., unless you have a very good spam filter set up.

Then what are the best email address with both user experience and less spams for company?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The choice depends as well on how you want to come across; formal and professional, or personal and relatable. If you want to be the former, you send emails from more abstract domain names, like info@, blog@, or hello@ for example. 
Depending on the content and images + links used in the email, it shouldn't matter if you use a more spam sensitive email address (@support, @webmaster, @sales etc.).

If you want to come across as more personal with the content, consider using a designated person who sends every email, or make it appear to be sent by them each time. Then use email addresses like john@ or johnS@. This makes people believe more readily that they have been mailed personally and more time and effort was spent on the content in the email.

The choice depends on how you want the receiver to perceive you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the **email address** is of paramount importance.

Take a look at [**how spam filters work**](https://www.ltnow.com/email-spam-filters-work/)

It is very important to make sure you don't tick off any of the red-flag checks on a spam filter. **[This article](https://mailchimp.com/resources/guides/avoid-spam-filters/)** should be a good read.

Keep in mind that the following things contribute more than the email address itself:

- What goes in the email
- To whom it is sent
- How many urls and images it has
- How focused is the "sent to" group

Answer (score 0):

Basically, email addresses like '*support@example.com*' and '*sales@example.com*' tend to be marked as spam by your inbox's spam detection intelligence. For email domains like gmail, spam detection will most probably be carried out by self-learning algorithms, based on predictive analysis and historical data. Most spammed mails are generally from sales and support departments of companies, and much like that, the machine also has a conception that the spams are majorly sent by these departments.

Having said this, it is also essential to keep the emails clear and unambiguous, and if it is a sales generated mail, then the sender should know that by just looking at the sender's address. So what do you do?

Maybe you could append certain terms to the sender's address, which not only bypasses spam filters, but also increases the clarity of the source.

Try email ID's like:

- *inside_sales@example.com*
- *outbound_sales@example.com*
- *customersupport@example.com*

**But then again, this is just one suggestion, out of many that can be applied for this situation.**